# division script in Perl

Tags: perl, division

I have a problem with a script in Perl.

I have a text file as input

```
Hello -> good 0.1 0.2 0.3
Hello -> morning 1 2 0.6
```

the script make the division like this : (output)

```
Hello |||good ||| 0.1/0.2 0.2/0.3 2.718
Hello ||| morning ||| 1/2 2/0.6 2.718
```

This is my current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(:5.10);
my ($fichier1) = "fichier1.txt";

open my $FIC1, "<", $fichier1, or die "impossible ouvrir $fichier1 $! \n";
open(FICHIERNOUVELLES, ">resultat.txt");

while (my $line1 = <$FIC1>) {
    chomp $line1;
    my ($texte, $value1, $value2, $value3) = ($1, $2, $3, $4) if $line1 =~ /^([a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏñœ=ÒÓÔÕÑÖæñßÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóô-õöùúûüý@#-%&*_\s]+)([.\d]+)$/;

    my $tot_val1 =sprintf("%.15f", $value1 * $value2);
    my $tot_val2 =sprintf("%.15f", $value2 * $value3);

    print "$texte $tot_val2\n";
    print FICHIERNOUVELLES "$texte ($tot_val2)\n";
}
close FICHIERNOUVELLES;
close $FIC1;
```

i have 2 errors in my script :

> "Use of uninitialized value $texte in concatenation (.) or string at
>   perl.pl line 18,  line 1.
>
> Use of uninitialized value $value2 in multiplication (*) at perl.pl
>   line 14,  line 2.

Any idea please?
many thanks

Comment: C'est clair comme le cul de d'Oussama à 200 pieds de fonds dans la mer noire.

Comment: Is there any question somewhere ? Or we have to guess what's going wrong, what you expect ?

Comment: i have 2 errors in my script "Use of uninitialized value $texte in concatenation (.) or string at perl.pl line 18, <$FIC1> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $value2 in multiplication (*) at perl.pl line 14, <$FIC1> line 2.

Comment: Put this in your original post

Answer (score 1):

The problem :

you try to retrieve captures 4 times :

```
($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

but you have only 2 capturing groups in your regex.

A capturing group is what you put inside `()` in your regex.

A good start is reading [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching)

Comment: So i have to change this part `$line1 =~ /^([a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏñœ=ÒÓÔÕÑÖæñßÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóô-õöùúûüý@#-%&*_\s]+)([.\d]+)$/;` ?

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answered, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputations ;)

Comment: @CyrineEzzahra Perhaps you should investigate the use of predefined character classes instead of trying to build your own. That looks horrible to maintain. `ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏñœ=ÒÓÔÕÑÖæñßÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóô-õöùúûüý@#-%&*_\s`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't correspond to your question, so I am struggling to understand what you need here. For instance, you ask for

```
Hello |||good ||| 0.1/0.2 0.2/0.3 2.718
```

in your output, but your code *multiplies* the values. And I can't tell where `2.718` comes from (is it just the value of *e*?)

However, you should use `split` to separate your data into columns. This code shows the idea.

The value of `$tot_val2` isn't displayed, because that is how it was in your own code. Also, I wasn't sure whether you wanted the first or the second text field. I have shown the first. The second is in `$colonnes[0]` if you need it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use 5.010;

my ($fichier1) = 'fichier1.txt';

open my $fic1, '<', $fichier1;
open my $fn,   '>', 'resultat.txt';

while (<$fic1>) {
    my ($texte, $reste) = split /\s*->\s*/;
    my @colonnes = split ' ', $reste;
    my ($value1, $value2, $value3) = @colonnes[1..3];

    my $tot_val1 =sprintf('%.15f', $value1 * $value2);
    my $tot_val2 =sprintf('%.15f', $value2 * $value3);

    print "$texte $tot_val2\n";
    print $fn "$texte ($tot_val2)\n";
}

close $fn;
```

**output**

```
Hello 0.060000000000000
Hello 1.200000000000000
```